# UIScrollView does not move view ontop of keyboard iPad

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have several text fields on screen. When I tap inside of the one towards the bottom, the keyboard appears over them.

I've referred to apple's documentation and used the following code to try and tackle this.

```
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = nil;
}
```

What i'd like to happen, when the keyboard appears the text fields that in side the scroll field will move up. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Write my code and your problem will solve .....

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code for Move the view up..........

```
   -(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField  
    {
      [self slideViewUpForTextField:textField];
    }

 -(void) slideViewUpForTextField:(UITextField *)textField
   {

    CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 3.0 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
        heightFraction = 1.0;

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    else
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


 }
```

And write these on top of the class
  And After #import"".....

```
       static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
       static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
       static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
       static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 158; 
       static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;
```

This is also write ....

```
 -(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField*) textField
   {

      CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
      viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

      [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
     [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
     [UIView commitAnimations];


   }
```

Comment: What do I need to declare animatedDistance as?

Comment: I've added all of that, but need to declare animatedDistance?

Comment: in your .h you have to declere Delegate for UITextField

Comment: Yep <UITextFieldDelegate>

Comment: Aha - Added a breakpoint to each method. There not been called! for some reason?